# how to get capacitor to use a different targetSdkVerion

Tags: android, node.js, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

The version of capacitor that I using in my node app is `"^4.5.0"`.

When I run

`npx cap build android`

it will create the `android` directory, which will contain the `variables.gradle` file:

```
ext {
    minSdkVersion = 22
    compileSdkVersion = 32
    targetSdkVersion = 32
    androidxActivityVersion = '1.4.0'
    androidxAppCompatVersion = '1.4.2'
    androidxCoordinatorLayoutVersion = '1.2.0'
    androidxCoreVersion = '1.8.0'
    androidxFragmentVersion = '1.4.1'
    coreSplashScreenVersion = '1.0.0-rc01'
    androidxWebkitVersion = '1.4.0'
    junitVersion = '4.13.2'
    androidxJunitVersion = '1.1.3'
    androidxEspressoCoreVersion = '3.4.0'
    cordovaAndroidVersion = '10.1.1'
}
```

Google now requires the use of `targetSdkVersion = 33`.

For example, is there something that I add to the `capacitor.config.ts` file in order to accomplish this?

Comment: You have to update to capacitor 5 and all the plugins you use to their 5.x version

Answer (score 0):

with the new Developer policies, Google Play requires all applications to be built for targetSDKVersion 33 to support Android 13 and + with API Level 33 or so, It is a mandatory requirement to change your targetSDKVersion to 33 to allow future updates via play store.

With that context: All you need to do is change `targetSDKVersion = 33` from 32 in your `variables.gradle` file and rebuild and sync your application.

Now you are good to go for adding the bundles in play console. hope that helps. :)